# hook_node_insert() and drupal_goto conflicts with each other?

Tags: hooks

I find some strange problem. I use hook_node_insert(). In order to create the other node after the user create the specific node! Then, I redirect the user to the other pages
But there are some error messages that i can't figure out!

the below code is my hook_node_insert()

```
function campaign_node_insert($node)
{
    global $user;
    global $base_url;

    if($node->type=="my_content_type")
    {

            $userid=$user->uid;

        /**

                My code is right here !


               **/


               drupal_goto('/user/'.$userid);


          }
}
```

My error Message is as belowed :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use drupal_goto() in hook_node_insert() and other node_hooks too. The reason is that there is a queue of hooks that are executed on node insert and if you run drupal_goto() in some hook - all other hooks which goes after will not execute!

If you need redirect user after node insert to some url - implement hook_form_alter for node_form and add new submit callback $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'my_module_submit_callback'. In this callback you will get $form_state with all $node fields and you can perform you redirect by specifying $form['#redirect'] = 'some/url'.

Comment: oh~i see, thank you very much! i almost make a big mistake!

Comment: Another point is that, even if it would work, it would also be executed for nodes that are created through other means than the UI. For example a migration, feeds or some other background process.

Comment: Hello,i use $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][]=campaign_add_record_callback; and create function campaign_add_record_callback doesn't work. :( the error message shows that "campaign_add_record_callback " is an undefined constant

Comment: Cobenash, you have forgotten quotes around function name, try $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][]='campaign_add_record_callback';

Answer (score 0):

Eugene is correct, although for D7 your submit handler should contain `$form_state['redirect'] = 'some/url'`.

You can look at the [`node_form_submit()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_form_submit/7) function to see how Drupal core handles this.