# Drupal 7, creation of new node, how redirect to the edit page of the new node

Tags: nodes

When I create a new node in my website, I want to be redirect to the edit page of the new node. 
I see several hook, but according to [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/37680/hook-node-insert-and-drupal-goto-conflicts-with-each-other) its not possible use drupal_goto..

Is there a way for me ? I prefer a programming approach
Thanks =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a custom module, use this code, and don't forget to replace MYMODULE_ with your module machine name :

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'my_content_type_node_form': // Replace my_content_type with yours
      $form['#submit'] = array_merge(array('MYMODULE_my_content_type_node_form_submit'), $form['#submit']);
    break;
}

function MYMODULE_my_content_type_node_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $initial_values = $form_state['build_info']['args'][0];
  $form_state['redirect'][] = drupal_get_destination();
  $form_state['redirect'][] = array('destination' => 'node/' . $initial_values->nid . '/edit');

  unset($_GET['destination']);
  $_GET['destination'] = 'node/' . $initial_values->nid . '/edit';
  drupal_static_reset('drupal_get_destination');
  drupal_get_destination();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help =) But the nid in 'values' is null :/ ($values['nid'] = null)

Comment: I've edited my code, retry with the new one